# Benefits to be gained from cloning immutable objects in Java

Tags: java

Let's say we have a Java object that has only primitive fields marked as final and as such is immutable.

Now several threads need the information contained in this object to do their work, so one has two choices:

1. Hand the reference to a single instance to all threads.
2. Create a clone/copy of the object for each thread.

Essentially the question boils down to this: Internally, does the JVM gain any benefits from copying the object, for example because reads become more efficient, or would it be a mere waste of memory because it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, if said threads run on different CPU cores, there will be multiple copies of the single object anyway, due to caches. As such, there is no real benefit to cloning the object, and in fact may hurt performance if multiple threads end up on the same processor.

In fact, cloning an immutable object seems counter-productive, since in this situation immutability serves the purpose of creating a shared, read-only object for all threads to use safely.

Answer (score 4):

All the benefits are had when no cloning happens, including the one you mention: the reads can only be more efficient if all threads read the same memory locations. For example, if two threads are assigned to the same core, its cache can satisfy the reads of both threads.

Answer (score 2):

Immutable objects greatly simplify your program, since they :

1.are simple to construct, test, and use

2.are automatically thread-safe and have no synchronization issues

3.do not need a copy constructor

4.do not need an implementation of clone

5.allow hashCode to use lazy initialization, and to cache its return value

6.do not need to be copied defensively when used as a field
make good Map keys and Set elements (these objects must not change state 
while in the collection)

7.have their class invariant established once upon construction, and it never 
needs to be checked again

8.always have "failure atomicity" : if an immutable object throws an exception,
 it's never left in an undesirable or indeterminate state

Source : http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

Comment: You should quote [your source](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) when you copy something.

Comment: @assylias thanks. I have edited and provided a link to source :)

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of using immutable objects is that you can share them in a thread safe manner so there is no point in manually copying/cloning them.

Note that in your case, if two threads run on separate CPUs for example, there might be several copies of the fields in each CPU's cache anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the main benefit of immutability is what's called "safe publishing", which means you may safely give references to the object to many threads/processes without fear of any complications.

Just give the same reference to everyone - cloning negates this benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a waste of memory.  It is much less memory-intensive to create new references to the same memory addresses, rather than copying all the information again and again.  You gain nothing through cloning in this scenario, except perhaps in some rare case when you are using the object as a lock for a `synchronized` block or something like that.  But even then, this would be an odd application.